# Prehung doors of nonstandard thickness

Tags: doors, prehung

We live in Canada and are currently renovating our upper floor. I plan to replace all the doors as part of the work.

We have door frames made from 2x6 wooden studs, which is not really standard - I understand that the walls usually have the thickness of 2x4 timber studs (thickness of 3.5 inches), plus the drywall (thickness of 0.5 inches on each side), so 4.5 inches is really more normal. But in our case, if I add the stud and the 2 drywalls, I get to 6.5 inches, which is too much for most generic prehung product.

Is there a generic supplier for doors with 6.5 inches frames? The only doors I find at generic retailers (like Rona or Home Depot) are for 4.5 inches. The only option we have found up to now is to get custom doors but these are quite more expensive.

Comment: Do you need or want to change the door frames?  Are they damaged or just ugly?  Any door of the same width will fit in the frames.  Replacing door frames just makes more work.

Comment: The problem is the thickness of the wall (made out of 2x6 inches studs), not the width of the doors. These are standard, like 32 inches or so.

Comment: Replacing just the door is a matter of undoing  about six screws.  Replacing the frame is removing the moulding, removing the nails holding the frame to the studs, putting the new all back in.  The doors don't really care that much if the frame is 4 inches or 12 inches.

Comment: If the OP means "renovation" like _I_ think of "renovation", then removal could involve a crow bar and sledge hammer, so delicate work may be right out. Other than that, your point stands.

Comment: @crip659 we would prefer to keep prehung doors as it's really simpler to install and we have quite a few to change. These usually come for a very specific thickness (4-5/8 inches). I think that the answer below from FreeMan is the simplest, given our current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We live in an old house (1890s) that was built with 2x4 walls (back when they were actually 2x4) and ran into this issue when we put in a single door where there had been a double.

We used a standard door/frame combo, then purchased and cut some 1" material (same thickness as the door frame itself) to make a jamb extension to fill out the rest of the wall thickness. You may be able to order a "standard" door with a factory applied jamb extension for not significantly more than the standard door (instead of going full custom). It's worth asking about.

Since we didn't like the look of the seam in the door jamb, we resawed some 2x4" to make thin (roughly 1/4") "vanity panels" that we nailed up on the extended side of the frame. It makes the door stop trim look slightly thinner on that side, but, even knowing it's there, I never see the difference.

We stained the "vanity panel" in place with the rest of the door frame and now you can't really tell that it's there.

You'd need to do the same for your doors, but your jamb extension would be deeper (2" vs our 1/2") and your "vanity panel" would have to be made from wider stock, but, you may still be able to make them out of 2x4" because the door stop trim takes up some of that space.

An extra 2x4 (or even 2x6 if necessary) and a few hours work will be a lot less expensive than a custom door.

Answer (score 2):

Jamb extensions will work, but a real door supplier can provide doors with custom jamb depth. They might cost a tiny bit more than big box doors, but you’ll also probably get slightly better quality.